# Chronological list of Algebraic Systems

Tags: abstract-algebra, big-list

In "A Book of Abstract Algebra", Second Edition by Charles C. Pinter, he states

"Other exotic algebras arose in a variety of contexts, often in connection with scientific problems. There were “complex” and “hypercomplex” algebras, algebras of vectors and tensors, and many others. Today it is estimated that over 200 different kinds of algebraic systems have been studied, each of which arose in connection with some application or specific need."

Is there a chronological list of these more than **200** algebraic systems anywhere?

Comment: "Chronological" is maybe too much of a demand. But similar questions have already been asked for. For example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/627444/305862)

Comment: Chronological ordering would be very useful for a historical perspective, but even if that is not possible, any enumeration would be useful.

Comment: Try asking in History of science and mathematics stackexchange